# 12.04lts won't fully burn onto DVD

Tags: 12.04, dvd

After burning the image of 12.04lts onto a disk it won't install and i find that the image is 4MB too big for a 4.35GB DVD disc. can any one help me here to cut down the file size or is it a case of just using a bootable usb stick instead.

Comment: Go BlueRay....or get a larger DVD (if you can).

Comment: Very few people have/use Blu-Ray burners or blank discs. Most DVD's I see are 4.4 GB at a minimum.

Comment: I don't believe you actually burned it. I think you checked the size and predicted it wouldn't burn. Either that or you got some mysterious 4.35GB DVDs that I have never heard of. More likely: DVD manufacturers mean 4,700,000,000 bytes when they say 4.7GB, and computer science types mean 4,700,000,000 / (2^30) = 4.377216101 (real) gigabytes. See @Kupiakos comment below.

Comment: The trick to make a boot USB from an ISO is to get a program called unetbootin. I've used it for many distributions and it hasn't failed yet. I'd suggest setting the "persistence" size to 9999 to minimize the chances for trouble when using the "try it out" boot option.

Answer (score 1):

if the DVD doesn't work go for usb here's the link for tutorial 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

if you are using windows go to

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Burn a Live image copy to a DVD which should be smaller.

Boot the live image.

Then install your system using the operating Live image.

Comment: ....? The process is:  1. The .iso is burned to DVD.  2. You boot to DVD.  3. DVD loads Live OS into RAM.  4. Ubuntu installer within the live OS copies the Ubuntu files to the hard drive from the DVD.  5. Reboot.  6. ???  7. Profit. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Many blank DVD's are larger than 4.35 GB - and the Ubuntu developers depended on this when they created it. For example, [here are 4.7 GB DVD-R's from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003ZDNZT2).

Comment: the discs themselves say they are 4.7 GB but when I looked at the discs to check them they were only 4.35GB. I tried it with 2 different brands of DVD-R 4.7GB.

Comment: Ah we might be confusing [Gibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (GiB) and [Gigabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) (GB) here.